# install new version of iOS Today widget , conflicting path error

Tags: path, ios8, ios8-today-widget

```
pkd[117] <Warning>: assigning plug-in com.xxx.xxx.xxx.Today(1.0) to plugin sandbox
pkd[117] <Warning>: enabling pid=43 for plug-in com.xxx.xxx.xxx.Today(1.0) E6C98121-A708-4ECC-8CC0-BB5489C8539C /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BD4EED02-D143-4EF2-8434-ED9301599D29/xxx.app/PlugIns/Today.appex
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.SpringBoard.43) <Warning>: Attempt to re-bootstrap service from different path, will use existing: com.xxx.xxx.xxx.Today
    **existing path:** /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/4BF19B1E-F0E3-498C-B33F-BDD13685C59E/xxx.app/PlugIns/Today.appex
    **conflicting path:** /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BD4EED02-D143-4EF2-8434-ED9301599D29/xxx.app/PlugIns/Today.appex
```

Comment: This problem does not occur when installed App in AppStore

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue with the same error message using:

```
launchctl remove com.xxx.xxx.xxx.Today
```

Then try again.

Comment: Where should i run launchctl? on iPhone?

Comment: ah sorry, didn't see that it's an iOS problem. Unless you jailbreaked it this solution (actually for Mac) will not help.